# Fetching data from localhost

Tags: cocoa, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP and I'm trying to fetch some data out of a php file.
If I put the file on my webserver, it works, but locally it doesnt. Seems like Xcode doenst "find" my localhost.. any ideas?

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/root/juraQuiz/test.php"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Can you write the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error, it simply doesnt show anything, NSLog return nothing (I put my code above) When I use http://www.ANYDOMAIN.de/test.php it works!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load data from URL with NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118076/load-data-from-url-with-nsdata)

Comment: Don't repeat a question you posted less than hour earlier.

Comment: sorry, I didnt know hw to put it up again.

Comment: do you know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet, so I've had to answer.

I would try seeing if the url is actually resolvable by using NURLs method and check the error.
`-(BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error`

Its possible your local server isn't using normal http ports and is using something random which you'll have to include in the url i.e. "localhost:3000/page.php"

Also, for remote fetching of data maybe NSURLConnection or something similar is more appropriate?

Hope that helps in some way.